# Dropzonejs and Node/Multer photo uploads are not showing on the server.

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, express-router

Using DropzoneJs to upload files to a Node server using Multer, I am unable to save files nor see anything in the `req.file` or `req.files` object in the console.

Here is the HTML, with a sprinkle of EJS:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row dropzone_input_div">
        <h1 class="new_event_header">Add Your photos for <%= event.title %></h1>
        <div>
            <form class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" action="/testmedia" id="dropzoneFileUpload" name="mediaFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" value="<%= event._id %>" hidden name="id">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="dropzone_preview">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Dropzone JS file:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneFileUpload={
    paramName: "media",
    parallelUploads: 30,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    autoProcessQueue: true
}
```

Here is the Node/Express/Router I am using:

```
const multer        = require('multer');
// const upload        = multer({dest:'uploads/'})
const async         = require('async');
const dotenv        = require('dotenv');

require('dotenv').config({silence:true});

const router = express.Router();
//Add Mongo Models to use Mongoose
const { Event, User, Moments, Instant } = require("../models");

const b2 = new B2({
    accountId: process.env.B2_MASTER_APPLICATION_KEY,
    applicationKey: process.env.B2_WRITE_APPLICATION_KEY
});

//router.use('/testmedia',upload.single('uploadedFile'))
router.use(multer({dest: 'uploads/'}).single('file'));

const uploads = (req,res,next) => {
    console.log("hit uploads yall!");
    console.log(req.file);
    next();
}


const testMedia = (req,res) => {
    console.log("hit testMedia route");
    res.send("File uplaoded!")
}
```

My console.log files look like this...

```
hit uploads yall!
undefined
hit testMedia route
POST /testmedia 200 5.603 ms - 14
```

Any clue why I cannot see the files? They do not save to my /uploads file on my server (Ubuntu) and always show up `undefined` in the console?

Comment: I would probably try appending the files to a FormData object then posting that to /testmedia 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: I have enctype="multipart/form-data" in the html, wouldn't that do the same thing? Or are they different

Comment: Also looking through the request and also the response object, I have multi-art/form-data as the type. However after searching I see no pertinent file/media/form/form-data in the entire req/res.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend Eli, helped me solve this...

Steps I took:

1. had my browser console opened in Chrome to the network tab
2. uploaded a file
3. looked for the `testmedia` request
4. at the bottom of the window there was a Form Data section with  `file[0]:
   (binary)`
5. Inside my routes file I used this

   ```
   const express     = require('express');
   const passport    = require('passport');
   const crypto      = require('crypto');
   const flash       = require('express-flash');
   const xoauth2     = require('xoauth2');
   const B2          = require('backblaze-b2');
   const async       = require('async');
   const multer      = require('multer');

   const { User } = require("../models");

   const {
       testMedia
   } = require('../controllers/backblaze.controller')

   const router = express.Router();


   //*******************Middleware for Backblaze routes******************

   const storeImage = multer.diskStorage({
       destination: (req,file,cb) => {
           cb(null, 'uploads/')
       },
       filename: (req,file,cb)=> {
           cb(null,file.fieldname + '-'+ Date.now())
       }
   });

   const upload = multer({storage:storeImage})

   //*****THE ANSWER IS BELOW THIS LINE IN THE .single() method*****

   router.post("/testmedia", upload.single('file[0]'), testMedia);
   //router.post("/testmedia", upload.any(), testMedia);
   ```

The function I require is in another folder for `testMedia` and it looks like this

```
    const testMedia = (req,res) => {
console.log("hit testMedia route");
res.send("File uplaoded!")
}
```

I'm not doing anything with the file yet, but that was my solution, the architecture is a bit different but this question is about the steps above and getting the solution through the browser and calling it correctly in the `single('name')` method in multer